# Number of days in a month giving strange results

Tags: javascript

I've created the following function that should return the number of days in a month but I'm not getting expected results.

```
export const getNumberOfDaysInMonth = (year, month) => {

    const myDate = new Date(year, month - 1, 0);
    return myDate.getDate();
}
```

I'm passing `year = 2017` and `month = 6`. As you'll see I'm subtracting 1 from month because as I understand it, JS uses a 0 based numbering system for months.

This sets myDate to May 31, 2017 and the function returns 31 days.

If I change the formula to `const myDate = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);`, it does set the date to June 1, 2017 and returns 1 day as the number of days.

I can use a switch statement to return the number of days in a month but that seems cumbersome and it wouldn't even take into account leap years, etc. Is there an elegant way to get the total number of days in a particular month in a particular year?

For example, if I pass `year = 2016` and `month = 2`, I should get 29 not 28.

Comment: Like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/73d4vjx1/ Remember that day `0` is the **last** day in the previous month, so for february you really want to pass in `2` for the month, so you get march, but then because you pass `0` for the date you get the last date in february.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing

> const myDate = new Date(year, month - 1, 0);

you don't need to subtract `1` from the month. This is because the third parameter in the date function here, represents the `day` of the month, is set to `0` which actually means last day of the previous month. So just doing this

> const myDate = new Date(year, month, 0);

should give you the desired result of number of days in a month.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: Which is the same thing that adeno said in his comment to the original post, along with a fiddle example.

Comment: ...which he never got a response to, so didn't bother posting an answer.